# Cómo puedo desplazarme en la consola en c++

Tags: c++

Gracias por pasar de antemano.

Estoy resolviendo un problema pero tengo la siguiente duda:

Mi programa debe mostrar la siguiente interfaz al iniciar (Omitan las flechas por el momento):

[image: interfaz inicial]

Ahora, mi problema es que no se como hacer para empezar a llenar en la parte donde están las flechas porque al imprimir el cursor naturalmente aparece abajo de todo, y yo quiero que en cada espacio pueda ir llenando con los datos.

Para ser más claros les dejo lo que dice el enunciado:

"La aplicación debe mostrar la interfaz y campos de información visto en la Figura 1, para luego, controlar la posición del cursor de lectura para irse desplazando de manera ordenada hacia la posición de cada dato que usuario debe ingresar."

Estoy usando dev c++ en windows 10

Espero me hayan entendido, y gracias de antemano.

Comment: eso depende de cada OS, ¿cual es tu OS?

Comment: estoy usando dev c++ en windows 10

Comment: entonces edita tu pregunta y añade esa información relevante, por otro lado te recomiendo investigar sobre la API de windows, debe de tener métodos para hacer lo que deseas.

Comment: ok, gracias, investigaré más.

Comment: quizas esto te ayude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732292/setting-the-cursor-position-in-a-win32-console-application